# overwriting part of Audio during recording in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

Is it possible to overwrite  a part of the recording with another recording.

1. When a recording is done, user gets back to a particular point of time in recording.
2. And right from that time, he initiates a recording, and this should overwrite the earlier recording.

Is this possible with AVFoundation Framework available in  iPhone?

Comment: I think you might be on the wrong board.
mybe your ment to be on superuser?
idk if super user dals with embedded OS's

Comment: Hi, I am also need this kind of solution, if you have any samples means kindly share me, because i am in critical situation,please help me

Comment: dinesh, I have not found  any solution for this.